# IndexOutOfBoundsException when reading from stream

Tags: java, io

I wrote a Java method to send an instruction to a remote device via serial port and get a known number of bytes as the answer. The code runs on RaspberryPi, using librxtx-java library. The remote device was verified to send the answer of expected length.

The code below is the last part of this method where RaspberryPi waits for all the bytes of the answer for up to a given time "t_max".

The code as it is throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException during `System.arraycopy`. If I wrap the arraycopy instruction by try...catch and print out the pointer variable at catch, there is indeed an index overflow.

However, if I uncomment the line which prints out the pointer value, there is no more exception. Even replacing this line by `System.out.println("X");` makes the exception gone, but not does the `System.out.print("X");` for example.

I tried changing the variables to volatile but no more luck. How can printing out to terminal change the value of a variable?

```
long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long t = t0;
byte[] answer = new byte[answerLength];
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[answerLength];
int numBytes = 0;
int answerPointer = 0;
while (t - t0 < t_max) {
    try {
        if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (numBytes > 0) {
        // System.out.println("answerPointer="+answerPointer);
        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, answer, answerPointer, numBytes);
        answerPointer = answerPointer + numBytes;
    }

    if (answerPointer == answerLength) {
        return (answer);
    }

    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Side comment: don't use `available()` to determine whether there are bytes left to read. Instead, just stop when `read` returns `-1`. Also, please include your stacktrace in your question as it may help us.

Comment: there is a few issues here: an empty catch for `Exception` is bad, very bad indeed. A lot of strange issues can be swallowed here which make your code later behave badly. Another thing is the way you are reading by looping as fast as you can and checking for available bytes.

Comment: Reinitialize your numBytes to 0 just after your while(...) { and catch your exception!!!

Comment: @Matthias & Tyco: The catch was not empty in fact, I deleted a call to another method from the code before posting in order not to encumber too much. But this exception was never thrown.

Comment: @Tyco & positiveCoder: of course, putting `numBytes=0;` after while(...) helped, I should have noticed it before. But I still don't understand how sending to stdout can change the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried verifying if the output stream and input stream are linked in any way? May be the input stream is reading from the output-stream and '\n' (new line) is being used as the end of stream character. Can you try printing out to a print-stream wrappend around byte-array-output-stream instead of standard-out and see if doing a ps.println("X") causes an exception? If it does cause an exception then possibly the standard output and input stream are linked and that is why doing a System.out.println("X") makes the exception go away.

Also, [volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java) keyword is used in the context of threads. It will not have any effect in a single thread environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked" streams? The input stream reads from serial port, the output stream writes to stdout.

Comment: By linked streams, I meant to ask if the output stream was writing into the input stream in any manner. If you are sure they are not then what I have said above is not the answer and you can ignore it. Otherwise you need to check. Double check if the output stream is not writing to the serial port that you are reading from !

Answer (score 0):

If the code `inputStream.available()` throws an exception on second iteration of `while (t - t0 < t_max)` variables `numBytes` and `readBuffer` stay initialized with old values. Try to wrap all code in block `while (t - t0 < t_max)` into `try {} catch {}` and don't hide an exception.